# Why was this answer spam or offensive?

Tags: support, review-queues, low-quality-posts, spam, specific-audit

I was just going through the Low Quality Posts queue and failed a test with the following answer:

[Spam/Offensive Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24993201)

Screenshot:

[image: Deleted question]

Reading the answer and following the link within the answer, it didn't strike me that this was spam or offensive, so, although it was not in any way a brilliant answer, I clicked Looks OK, and promptly failed the test.  There is only one button to say "I Understand".  There is no button to say "I don't understand"! Hence I seek guidance here.

I noticed that this was deleted by "Community", which I believe is an automatic programme.  Is it possible that it was flagged because it contains the acronym CRUD?  I realise that as an acronym, this has certain unfortunate associations, but I would have thought the term was reasonably well understood in the programming world (Create,Read, Update, Delete), not to merit automatic deletion.

Or was the post deleted for some other reason?  If so, please could someone enlighten me, to help me with future review tasks?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The complete answer says:

> Any Web Application, API is very useful for communicate with another application. There are many web tutorial and ready made library available on web for use API inside in Codeigniter.
>
> But if you want to learn, how to make your own API in Codeigniter application, then I have found [link removed].
>
> In this post, you can found how to make API from scratch, and by using this post source code, you can make your own customize method as per your requirement. So, If you are looking for Codeigniter REST Ful CRUD API. Then post will help you. Best of Luck.

The answer is absolutely useless without the link (which would have made it "link only", and thus "not an answer". So even without the SPAM angle, clicking "looks OK" was certainly the wrong call.

On top of that, the link points to the same domain that the user has on their profile (link removed) as their URL. This is nothing but an attempt to promote that tutorial.

Comment: I did consider Link Only, but thought there was enough accompanying text not to warrant this. I would never have considered clicking the user's profile on a link answer. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @JonathanWillcock "Enough text" doesn't matter when the text is useless fluff or like in this case _clearly_ promotional text.